# looping collection in knockoutjs in to ul

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have json collection like this

0: {FamilyDetailId:1, Name:Daniel, GenderId:1, Dob:/Date(1375554600000)/,…}

1: {FamilyDetailId:3, Name:Askar, GenderId:1, Dob:/Date(1375554600000)/,…}

```
    var employeeFamilyModel;
function bindModel(data) {
     employeeFamilyModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(employeeFamilyModel, document.getElementById("collapseOne"));
}



 function loadData (employeeGuid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/HumanResource/EmployeeProfile/EmployeeProfileFamily?employeeGuid=" + employeeGuid,
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            bindModel(result);
        }
    });
```

};

view

```
 <ul data-bind="foreach: employeeFamilyModel">
    <li data-bind="text: Name"></li>
 </ul>
```

my problems is to display each collection in new UL list 
ex :

```
    <ul>
    <li> Name: Daniel </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li> Name: Askar </li>
</ul>
```

how to achieve this in knockoutjs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate, you simply need to move your `foreach` binding 'up' a level, so that the `<ul>` is included for each data element in your view model.

**JS**:

```
employeeFamily =  ko.observableArray([{Name: 'John Doe', Owner: 'John'},
                                  {Name: 'Jane Doe', Owner: 'Jane'}])

ko.applyBindings(employeeFamily, document.getElementById("collapseOne"));
```

**Html**:

```
 <div  id = 'collapseOne' data-bind="foreach: employeeFamily">

   <label data-bind="text: 'This list belongs to ' + $data.Owner"></label>
   <ul>
     <li data-bind="text: $data.Name"></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

**Result**:

```
This list belongs to John
  John Doe
This list belongs to Jane
  Jane Doe
```

I added the owner attribute to emphasize that each `<ul>` was bound to a different `$data` element. See [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdTwU/)

Answer (score 1):

Everything you have inside ko foreach block will be repeated like foreach loop. And everything you have in ko text will just output without any element around.

```
<!-- ko foreach: employeeFamilyModel -->
<ul>

   <li>Name: <!--ko text: Name--><!--/ko--></li>
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: can you elaborate more your answer ?

Comment: the syntax of <!-- ko foreach: elements --> can be viewed @ http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html          under Note 4: Using foreach without a container element.                                The project I currently work on had an issue with that syntax, but I cannot recall exactly what it was.